# Line-neutral vs Line-Line same voltage

Tags: transformer

I have a 3 conductor (Line1, Line2, ground) (240V) wire that goes to a step-down transformer to get 120V. Since the transformer output is 120V between its line1 and line2 and there is no neutral, does this affect what kinds of devices can be plugged in? Hope I explained that clearly enough...

Comment: Does the transformer not have a ground?  The output at the same potential as ground should be the neutral.  I admit that I have never used a transformer like this, so a model number or similar model might help the question.

Comment: @AMC, can you post the model number of your transformer, and maybe a picture or diagram of its connection points, so that we can clear up whether this is a regular, isolating transformer, or a non-isolating autotransformer?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring and/or nameplate on your transformer?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a traditional, isolated transformer with separate primary and secondary windings, the output of your transformer as currently configured is *floating*, meaning that while there is 120V between line1 and line2, the voltage from either of those to ground could be anything, and can change over time.  If you want to make it a traditional hot/neutral setup, you can bond one of the two output lines to ground.  If you're wiring this as the input into a breaker panel, make the bond there -- this makes it a main service panel, from a separately derived service, rather than a subpanel.  The bonded lead then becomes your neutral, and the other is your 120V hot.

If instead your transformer is really an autotransformer, where the primary and secondary windings are actually the same thing, then you cannot ground one of the outputs.  In this case, the voltage is not floating, but where exactly it is depends on the transformer's construction.  I'd recommend measuring from each of the hot leads to ground to see if one of them is at 0V already, or if they are each approximately 60V from ground, or something else.

To check if it's an autotransformer or a regular transformer, check if there's any continuity between the primary windings (input) and secondary windings (output).  If there is, then it's an autotransformer.

Comment: Why bond against ground, as opposed to neutral? If you want a hot-*neutral*, I'd expect the bond to be to neutral, no?

Comment: The question has Line1, Line2, and ground as input.  There is no neutral available.

Comment: Duh, yeah, ok. Still, if a neutral was available and one wanted to feed a transformator from the two hots, which one should be used for bonding? (Really just curious)

Comment: If there was a neutral, it would already be bonded to ground in the main panel.  The way I understand it, the transformer is like having a separate supply, so you also bond to ground to avoid any slight drift in ground from one supply to the next even tho neutral should be at the same potential.

Comment: @Jeffrey, the point of bonding is simply to bring one of the hots to the local ground potential (which then forces the other one to be 120V away from ground).  If there's no input wire at ground potential, then you'd need to drive a ground rod to make one.

Comment: WHOA. You can't ground one of the transformer outputs, because it's a *step-down transformer* or autotransformer.  It only has a primary, not a secondary.

Comment: @Harper, step-down doesn't imply autotransformer.  Most of them are not, but if it is, then yes, you're right.  I'll edit that into my answer.

Comment: Every one of the [commonly available](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=step+down+transformer&i=electronics&ref=nb_sb_noss) "step-down transformers" that I've seen is an autotransformer.  I've been in search of cheap 120V/240V transformers I can backfeed to get 60VAC, to then rectify to ~75VDC at about 800W, with DC- grounded. That won't work with an autotransformer.

Comment: @Harper, there are literally thousands of them available at electronics suppliers... https://www.mouser.com/Power/Transformers/Power-Transformers/_/N-8u9n5?P=1y8s5skZ1y8s5sqZ1y8s5swZ1y8s5sgZ1y8s5smZ1yxu1vnZ1yzs0d5Z1y8s5svZ1yzs0d4Z1yc3sgdZ1y8s5sxZ1y8s5slZ1yc3tkjZ1y8s5syZ1y8s5srZ1yzuxsfZ1yvyg7kZ1ydl01yZ1z0wcy8Z1yctg5hZ1yzsnaoZ1yuyystZ1z0wd6nZ1ydl0z6Z1yzsn7lZ1ysxj68Z1yf16liZ1yzuxrrZ1ysxjzsZ1yctg26

Comment: And if you're buying via Amazon, yes (and note they mostly call themselves "voltage converter transformers"), but if you simply google "step down transformer", most of the results are the isolated type: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS822US823&q=step+down+transformer&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnnbearpnjAhWkCjQIHbMGAUsQsAR6BAgGEAE

Comment: @Harper, if you're rectifying to DC, aren't you in the component realm anyhow?  Surely you're not saying there's a UL listed complete device that's needs an input of 60VAC and will output 75VDC, yet doesn't have an internal transformer?

Comment: Oh gosh, I'm sorry, I understand what you mean now... *for my application*.  Yes, I've gone through all those, and I need a lot of power, ~1kw, so *truly isolating, typically component* ones that size are uneconomical for the cheap project that this is.

Comment: @Harper, ah that makes sense now.  Yeah, at the 1kVA range, it's never gonna be cheap, simply because that's a lot of copper and iron.

Answer (score 2):

You said "Step-down transformer", not "isolation transformer".

The commonly available step-down transformers are **autotransformers**. That means they only have a primary winding, no secondary at all. 120V is picked up at the *center tap*.    240V is applied to the top and bottom taps, and 120V is taken off the center and bottom taps.

Now, typically the bottom tap is considered to be "Neutral". But in North American style (and Philippines) 240V power, both legs of 240V are *not anywhere near neutral*, to be more precise, they are ~120V from neutral.   That means the center-tap of this transformer will be "somewhere in the neighborhood of ground (and where neutral would be)", but *not close enough to tie them together* - and anyway, that would violate the sacrosanct Only One Ground Bond rule.

Note that the *bottom* tap is "considered neutral" in these step-down transformers, but the *middle* tap is actually the one near ground.  So the polarity would be opposite what you'd expect, and I'd expect it to light "Hot-Neutral Reverse" on a magic-8-ball tester (this being more or less true).

The upshot is you should use double-insulated devices, which don't care about either wire being neutral.

If you wanted to do this *properly*, you would use an **isolation transformer**, treat the output of its secondary as a separate *main service*... establish ground via local ground rods, and pick an output wire to equipotential-bond to ground (to prevent floating).  Its name would be Neutral.